# How t match a variable captured via document.onkeyup against an array index in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop

I am building a Rock Paper Scissors game. what I am trying to do is capture the user input via document.onkeyup event, then compare it to an array of valid choices. If user choice is mataches any index within that array, an alert should show up confirming user choice. If not, an alert should show requesting a valid entry.

The problem is, JavaScript engine seems unable to capture the userChoice part regardless of what I do, unless it is a specifically defined string such as: var userChoice = "r". Here is the code below

```
document.onkeyup = function (event) {
  var userChoice = (event.key);
}

var validChoices = ["r" , "p" , "s"];

var choiceIsValid = false;

for (var i=0; i < validChoices.length; i++) {
    if(validChoices[i] === userChoice) {
    choiceIsValid = true;
  }
}

if(choiceIsValid) {
    alert("Your choice is " + userChoice);
} else {
  alert("Please make a valid choice");
}
```

Comment: put all your code inside keyup function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user presses a key, your code stores it in the `userChoice` variable but doesn't actually do anything with the stored value, since that's all you have included inside the keyup handler function.

To obtain the intended effect, you have to move the input handling part of your code inside the keyup function:

```js
var validChoices = ["r", "p", "s"];


document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  var choiceIsValid = false;

  var userChoice = (event.key);

  for (var i = 0; i < validChoices.length; i++) {
    if (validChoices[i] === userChoice) {
      choiceIsValid = true;
    }
  }

  if (choiceIsValid) {
    alert("Your choice is " + userChoice);
  } else {
    alert("Please make a valid choice");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place all your code within the `keyup` event function. Your code has to be told to run, if it's outside of that function it is never told to execute.

You don't need to iterate over an array to discover if something is included within it. You can use the Array `includes` method:

`arr.includes(item)`

which will return true or false. This also negates your use of a variable to store whether or not the choice is valid.

We can then use a ternary, since there are only two possible outcomes, to either alert that the typed key was valid and included in the valid choices array, or alert that it was not.

Example of ternary:

`(condition) ? (code for true) : (code for false);`

```js
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  var userChoice = event.key,
    validChoices = ["r", "p", "s"];

  (validChoices.includes(userChoice)) ?
  alert("Your choice is " + userChoice):
    alert("Please make a valid choice");
}
```